# Bin packing with different bins

Tags: algorithm

Consider a warehouse with a number of shelves(Bins) that have number, length, width, height and limit Weight capacity.

The Items that place in this warehouse are a number of cubes that have number, length, width, height and weight.

The algorithm must find the right place for Items so Bins have the lowest waste of space. and sum of weight of Items in each bin must not be more than its weight capacity.

Items are placed at the edge of Bins. Namely, any Items can't be placed on Items, behind Items and in front of Items.

I tried to write my problem as an integer linear programming model, here it is:

[image]

I tried this algorithm:

1_ Sort list of bins Smallest To Biggest.

2_ Sort list of items Biggest To Smallest.

3_ insert each item in first bin that have free space, by best fit algorithm.

It worked but can't swap bins when it's necessary. In other words it is not an optimized algorithm.

please help me :)

Comment: There isn't any algorithm that is going to work in all cases.  These problems are called "Packing Problems" and tried solving the problem 2000 years ago.  They tried to figure the optimal method for packing chariots when going to war.  You need a criteria to determine the best results.  Getting a solution by itself doesn't mean it is the optimal solution.  The only real answer is to try every combination.

Comment: "I tried to write my problem as an integer linear programming model." So what's the problem with that? You should be able to get an optimal solution using that approach. The greedy approaches of course are just approximate

Comment: Are the dimensions of the items to be considered in a geometric or non-geometic way (the linear programming model seems use non-geometric constriaints)?

Comment: There are a number of open-source integer programming solvers out there -- why not use one? Also -- the sort of problem you have (with decision variables with at most two indices) is of the sort that is easily formulated as a spreadsheet model which can be optimized by solver add-ins (such as Excel's built-in solver or the *What's Best* add-in).